# Amazon RDS: is there java API for PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I'm new to Amazon RDS and stuck in a vast amout of information about it. So, my brain is rejecting new information now, that's why I decided to ask this question =)

The question is: is there java API for PostgreSQL in Amazon RDS? I mean something like that:

```
AmazonPosgtreSQL aps = new AmazonPostreSQL(...);
aps.connect(...);
aps.persist(...);
aps.get(...);
```

There AmazonPostgreSQL is some class provided by SDK.

I have read some manuals, including user guide about Amazon RDS, and as far as I understand, there is no such API. We just create a DB Instance in cloud and Amazon just provides us with a link to it, am I right?

Comment: To connect to postgreSQL on RDS you would just use the normal postgreSQL java driver. The SDK provides methods to control RDS instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java APIs for RDS are part of the broader [AWS Java SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/). The APIs exposed there can be used to start, modify, and destroy RDS instances.

Data connectivity is via PgJDBC. The AWS SDK for RDS doesn't know or care about actually accessing the data, just managing the instances.

So there's no single API like you describe, though you could probably write one as an extension/wrapper for an ORM like Hibernate, using the AWS SDK to provide automatic provisioning of servers when persistence units are created.